# Apollo Client fetchMore - cache updated but data returned by useQuery not updated

Tags: apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo, apollo-server

I'm implementing infinite scrolling functionality using my server's pagination.

The following is the function that get triggered whenever a new page needs to be fetched from the server (because the user activates the infinite scrolling).

```
const fetchMorePostsHandler = async () => {
    if (!postsLastKey) {
      return;
    }

    await fetchMore({
      variables: {
        input: {
          startKey: postsLastKey,
        },
      },
    });
  }, [postsLastKey, fetchMore]);
```

This is my client.

```
new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache: new InMemoryCache({
    typePolicies: {
      Query: {
        fields: {
          posts: {
            keyArgs: false,
            merge(existing = [], incoming) {
              // the following console log prints out the correct cached posts whenever
              // fetchMore is executed
              console.log('merged:', [...existing, ...incoming.posts]);
              return [...existing, ...incoming.posts];
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  }),
});
```

This is the `useQuery` hook. I was expecting `data` returned by useQuery will be updated, after `fetchMore` is executed, the hook re-executed, but it is returning the original data when the query is first executed. However, I can see from the network tab a query with the right variabels is indeed sent to the server and result is being merged in the cache.

```
const { loading, data, fetchMore, refetch } = useQuery<PostsQuery>(ALL_POSTS_QUERY, {
    variables: {
      input: {
        type: PostType.SOMETHING,
      },
    },
    fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
  });
```

Does someone know what have I done wrong? How can I get back the updated posts from the cache and show it in my UI?